# Issuing authority of passport is only written in Cyrillic script. How to fill it into a Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, russian-citizens, russian-language

I am helping a Russian national fill out an application for a Norwegian Schengen visa (Type C).

The form asks for "Issuing authority". In the applicant's passport, this is only given in Cyrillic, (as ФМС 25011). I believe this refers to the Russian Federal Migration Service. However, the only thing that is written in the passport is "ФМС 25011".

The application form states:

> You can only use Latin letters, numbers and special characters.

What should I write in the application form for this field?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I see no reason why you should depart from general [transliteration table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian#Transliteration_table) of Russian. 
According to all standards, `С` is transliterated into `S`, so it will be

```
FMS 25011
```

And also space between organ name (**FMS**) and organ branch number (**25011**) should be preserved.